# Codeigniter & JQuery Hello world

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I cannot get Jquery working in CI.

I downloaded jquery from the official website. Now I have a simple

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_jquery"></script>
```

and than:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
       function () {
          alert('The document is ready.');
       }
    ); 
</script>
```

And alert does not show up. So what am I doing wrong..?

All this code is in my 'view'.

Comment: use this as scr="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js "

Comment: Check for any javascript error in console.

Comment: That path_to_jquery is just for here right? Because if that's what you actually have then it isn't loading jquery. See Milind's comment above for a correct path. (although why 1.7 I am not sure.)

Comment: "Check for any javascript error in console" ... please tell me more.

Comment: ok I tried ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js still nothing. than I added http:// to the begining of the url and bam! So looks like it has to do something with the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `javascript` enabled in your bowser

Add this script in `view` file and run

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If it doesn't work check your **page source** in **browser**.

**EDIT**

If U want load JQuery from your server just use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>file_path_in_app/jquery.js"></script>
```

**Suggestion**

U can use `firebug` tool to debug the these kind of errors..

Comment: I can accept this answer... but I really want to have jquery loaded from inside the application. I don't want to rely on google apis every time the page is loaded..

Comment: @user568021 believe me, they are much more reliable than any of the hostings you may choose, they load faster and sometimes they don't even need to be loaded as they are will be in your users cache before he accesses your webpage for the first time. If you really want them to load from your page, use `<?php echo site_url('path/to/jquery.js');?>` as CodeIgniter requires full URL's.

Comment: your code is incorrect. type="" ? i always thought it was src=""

Comment: @MRSrinivas place the path inside the brackets, it will be even better. And you're right, it's `base_url()`, not `site_url()` like I commented earlier.

Answer (score 1):

It bothers me that you have accepted the above answer as the correct one. Because it is incorrect the url was added into type="" and not src="".

This is the correct snippet:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You just download the latest jQuery plugin and add the

```
<script src=""></script>
```

With in the src you just maintain the file path to your jQuery api plugin.

Comment: Why would he download it when loading it from CDN is recommended.